# Ajax call. Proper way to send multiple data:

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json

I´m trying to make a ajax call with multiple data inputs.
When sending only one string of data i have used this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "php/update_lastordning.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: "elId=" + elId
});
```

With this i fetch it in PHP by:

```
$elId = $_POST['elId];
```

Now i´d like to send some more data.
How can i do it with the same syntax?

```
data: "elId=" + elId   ????
```

I guess i can use JSON:

```
data: {newPos: newPos, elId: elId}
```

But then i can´t fetch it with the same PHP syntax!?

```
$newPos = $_POST['newPos'];
```

Comment: Try `$_POST['data']['newPos']`

Comment: That isn't JSON. That is an object. Nothing shown in the code you've shared with us will prevent that from working. The best guess I have based on what you've shown us is that newPos contains an empty string instead of the value you expect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do exactly as you describe. Try the following:

In your frontend:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "backend.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {A: 1, B: 2}
});
```

which by the way is equivalent to:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "backend.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: "A=1&B=2"
})
```

and in backend.php:

```
<?php 
    echo "Variable A is ".$_POST["A"];
    // Variable A is 1
    echo "Variable B is ".$_POST["B"];
    // Variable B is 2
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use [FormData Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects), that post data as from submit

Comment: Using FormData for this is unnecessarily complex and has unnecessarily limited browser support. You don't appear to have identified what the problem is at all.

Answer (score -1):

You can use data: $('#form_id').serializeArray();

on server file do this-:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_POST); // if you are using post method 
die;
```

check your console